# How to attach a certificate to a C# client for an ODATA service?

Tags: certificate, odata, client-certificates

We have an ODATA service which is being secured using certificates. We are using AddWebReference to get the proxy in our C# code.

Is there a way to attach the certificate that is in our certificate store to this generated proxy class?

We can add the certificate using `HTTPClient`, but we would like to avoid using `HTTPClient` to talk to our ODATA service and prefer to use the AddWebReference method.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is probably 3 years too late for you, but hopefully someone else will be helped.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment.aspx) actually explains in great detail what is required.

You need to add a `ClientCertificate` property to the container generated by adding a web reference and use it. You can do this by creating a partial class that adds the behaviour:

```cs
public partial class YourContainer
{
    private X509Certificate clientCertificate = null;

    public X509Certificate ClientCertificate
    {
        get
        {
            return clientCertificate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                // if the event has been hooked up before, we should remove it
                if (clientCertificate != null)
                    this.SendingRequest -= this.OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
            }
            else
            {
                // hook up the event if its being set to something non-null
                if (clientCertificate == null)
                    this.SendingRequest += this.OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
            }

            clientCertificate = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs args)
    {
        if (null != ClientCertificate)
        {
            ((HttpWebRequest)args.Request).ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
        }
    }
}
```

On the instantiated container you can now set the `ClientCertificate` property with the certificate you need:

```cs
// Get the store where your certificate is in.
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

// Select your certificate from the store (any way you like).
X509Certificate2Collection certColl = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, yourThumbprint, false);

// Set the certificate property on the container.
container.ClientCertificate = certColl[0];

store.Close();
```

### WCF DataServices 5+ (not completely working)

Now if you're using WCF Dataservice 5+, then the SendingRequest event has been deprecated as indicated with the attribute `[Obsolete("SendingRequest2 has been deprecated in favor of SendingRequest2.")]` (not a typo on my side ;) ). I think you can still use it though, however, if you want to use SendingRequest2, your partial should look something like the following:

```cs
public partial class YourContainer
{
    private X509Certificate clientCertificate = null;

    public X509Certificate ClientCertificate
    {
        get
        {
            return clientCertificate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                // if the event has been hooked up before, we should remove it
                if (clientCertificate != null)
                    this.SendingRequest2 -= this.OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
            }
            else
            {
                // hook up the event if its being set to something non-null
                if (clientCertificate == null)
                    this.SendingRequest2 += this.OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
            }

            clientCertificate = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs args)
    {
        if (null != ClientCertificate)
        {
            ((HttpWebRequestMessage)args.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me for non-batch requests (found by trial and error as I couldn't find a lot of documentation about the differences between the `SendingRequest` and `SendingRequest2`).

However I seem to be experiencing some trouble now with `args.RequestMessage` being of type  instead of `HttpWebRequestMessage` resulting in `InvalidCastExceptions`. Which is actually the reason I ended up on this question. It seems that it only goes wrong with Batch operations. The `InternalODataRequestMessage` has a private member requestMessage of type `ODataBatchOperationRequestMessage`. It doesn't seem to have any property to which I can add client certificates.

I have posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21237052/210336) about that specific issue and will change this answer if the implementation I provided here turns out to be the problem.