# How to solve this InvalidCastException while applying ClientCertificate to WCF DataService Client?

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, client-certificates

I have used the examples in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment.aspx) to add client certificate authentication to my WCF Data Service. I had to change the example slightly because I am using WCF DataService 5.6 in which the `SendingRequest` event has been deprecated and replaced by `SendingRequest2`.

Basically this meant changing the following event handler:

```
private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs args)
{
    if (null != ClientCertificate)
    {
        ((HttpWebRequest)args.Request).ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
    }
}
```

To:

```
private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs args)
{
    if (null != ClientCertificate)
    {
        ((HttpWebRequestMessage)args.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
    }
}
```

This seems to work. However now I get the following `InvalidCastException` on some actions:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.InternalODataRequestMessage' to type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage'.

I haven't been able to identify with 100% accuracy which actions these are, but it seems consistently on the SaveChanges method (see stacktrace below:)

```
at MyNamespace.MyContainer.OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(Object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs args)
at System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper.FireSendingRequest2(Descriptor descriptor)
at System.Data.Services.Client.BatchSaveResult.GenerateBatchRequest()
at System.Data.Services.Client.BatchSaveResult.BatchRequest()
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
```

I came to the modification from `SendingRequest` to `SendingRequest2` by trial and error, so I wonder if I overlooked something there. Or is this completely unrelated and should I just add an `&& args.RequestMessage is HttpWebRequestMessage` to the if statement in the handler?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are sending a batch request. A batch request contains several internal requests which are InternalODataRequestMessage. SendingRequest2 will apply the OnSendingRequest action into both the $batch request and it's internal requests.

You can try following code

```
private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs args)
{
    if (null != ClientCertificate && !args.IsBatchPart)
    {
        ((HttpWebRequestMessage)args.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
    }
}
```

args.IsBatchPart returns true if this event is fired for request within a batch, otherwise returns false.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the batch operation request wraps multiple requests and that the event is fired for each one of the containing requests as well. I always understood that the batch operation was one request describing multiple operations. It's been a while since I worked on this code. I'm not sure if I have the opportunity to test this out soon. When I have, I'll check back in with the result. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem occurs when I perform a batch operation.

I tried to dig through the `InternalODataRequestMessage` to see if I could add client certificates to that somehow using reflection and the DataServices source. I found the instance of `InternalODataRequestMessage` has a private member `requestMessage` of type `ODataBatchOperationRequestMessage`. By looking at the [source code](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.6.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0/Microsoft.Data.OData) I couldn't any way to add a certificate.

What I did notice is that I can actually still use the deprecated `SendingRequest` event just like before. So that's what I did and everything seems fine.

I feel like there should be a way to use a client certificate without using deprecated methods. So if someone has an answer that shows that, I'll accept that.